# How to display output according to initial format set in matlab?

Tags: matlab

for instance I had set the display format of a program at the very beginning such as `format shortG` and then I would like to use the `fprintf` command to display a certain values.

For example I have

```
x = 1.23456789
```

> y = 12.3456789

If under format shortG it will show x = 1.2346 and y = 12.346. My question is what format I should use when using the `fprintf` because like if using `%.4f` y will equal to 12.3457 which is not what I want. Thanks for every single help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `g` instead of `f`:

```
>> fprintf('%.5g\n',y)
12.346
>> fprintf('%.5g\n',x)
1.2346
```